# Why helm ignoring node port section?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm tring install helm chart with nodeport on specific port. For example: `30005`, but helm ignoring nodeport section.

```
==> v1/Service
NAME       TYPE      CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)         AGE
hello-app  NodePort  10.109.69.245  <none>       8080:32146/TCP  0s
```

I tried set specific port:

```
helm install --set service.type=NodePort,service.nodePort=30005 --name hello-app /home/ubuntu/hello-app
```

My `values.yaml` "service" section.

```
imagePullSecrets: []
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

service:
  type: NodePort
  port: 8080
  nodePort: 30005
```

My expected result:

```
==> v1/Service
NAME       TYPE      CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)         AGE
hello-app  NodePort  10.109.69.245  <none>       8080:30005/TCP  0s
```

Comment: can you share your Service definition

Comment: i'm sorry i forgot add to my /template/service.yaml this

  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      nodePort: {{ .Values.service.nodePort }}
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have somewhere in your service's helm template a typo, or skipped the fact, that variable names are case sensitive. Please double check it.

Take a look also at the official reference [nginx](https://github.com/helm/helm/tree/master/docs/examples/nginx) chart example, where [service](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/docs/examples/nginx/templates/service.yaml) helm template lets `type` and `nodePort` be configurable by the end user too, which works perfectly with helm overridden parameters (--set).

You can verify the manifest files rendered by helm before release installation with following command:

```
helm template --set service.type=NodePort --set service.nodePort=31000 --debug docs/examples/nginx/
```

**Last thing:**
 
Be sure, that specified by you nodePort is not in use already. 
You can do it using `--server-dry-run` option with `kubectl`, e.g.

`kubectl apply -f service-31000-nodeport-conflict.yaml --server-dry-run`

In case it's already occupied you would see similar error to this one, returned from API server:

```
The Service "release-name-nginx-conflict" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Invalid value: 31000: provided port is already allocated
```

Comment: The links are obsolete.